# Batch file to delete files with .bak extension

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

In batch, I want to delete all files *.bak in various folders on disk `c:\`.
Can anyone help me?

ex.:

```
all c:
del *.bak /s /a
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It can be a single command.

```
del /s /q /f c:\*.bak
```

Comment: Could you explain what the /s /q and /f parameters do?

Comment: @FranzDeschler: Type `del /?` on a command line and you get: `/f` = Forces deletion of read-only files. `/s` = Deletes specified files from the current directory and all subdirectories. Displays the names of the files as they are being deleted. `/q` = Specifies quiet mode. You are not prompted for delete confirmation.

Answer (score 20):

***Be extremely careful doing global deletes!*** You may get more than you ask for, especially in the way of headaches and lost time restoring your system.

With that being said:

```
C:
cd \
del /s /q /f *.bak
```

For more information, type `del /?` from the command prompt, which gives you this in Windows 7:

```
Deletes one or more files.

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

  names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
                Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
                directory is specified, all files within the directory
                will be deleted.

  /P            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
  /F            Force deleting of read-only files.
  /S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
  /Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
  /A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
  attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
                H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
                I  Not content indexed Files  L  Reparse Points
                -  Prefix meaning not

If Command Extensions are enabled DEL and ERASE change as follows:

The display semantics of the /S switch are reversed in that it shows
you only the files that are deleted, not the ones it could not find.
```