# Batch deleting exact file extensions

Tags: batch-file

I have .blk and .blkx files in the same folders, of wich im trying to delete only the .blk file. Ive attempted examples found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871544/batch-file-to-delete-files-with-bak-extension) as in `del "\folder\*.blk" /s`. I managed to get the chosen files deleted however the .blkx files were deleted too (other files werent so i assume its an issue with both the file having .blk in their extension).

How can i select only the .blk file?

Edit: I dont know why this post was marked a duplicate but the **above pinned post does not resolve the problem** (wich i already talked about not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have [SFNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) (short filenames) enabled on that drive, and the `.blkx` extension is mapped to `.blk` in the short 8.3 filename. Because of this, and because [wildcards match both long and short names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107715), `*.blk` returns both `.blk` and `blkx` files. To distinguish between them you'll need to run a `for` loop, check the actual extension, and delete each `.blk` individually.

```
    for %%b in (*.blk) do @(if /I "%%~xb" == ".blk" echo del "%%~b")
```

Remove `echo` from the above to actually delete the `.blk` files.

To recurse into subdirectories (like `del /s`) use `for /r` instead of `for`.

The command is written as to be used in a batch file (per the question tag). To run it at a command prompt, instead, replace the double percents `%%b` with single ones `%b`.

Comment: You should use `if /I` to match case-insensitively…